# PowerShell script for read the content of a site and restart a service

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell scripting and I need to write a script to get the content of a webpage and if the content is not "It Works" to restart a service.

This is what my code looks like:

```
$WebResponse= Invoke-WebRequest https://webpage.phpenter code here
$WebResponse.Content
$service = 'Service'
$logoutput = 'service restarted'
$Date = Get-Date
If ($WebResponse.Content -eq "It Works") {
Write-Host "OK"
}
Else {
Restart-Service $service -Force
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what's the question..?

Comment: The script doesn't work, it's restarting the service everytime, It's ignoring "It works" content. So i am doing something wrong and i need a help

Comment: Are you sure that `Content` just contains the string "It Works" ?

Answer (score 0):

`$WebResponse.Content` will contain a whole HTML file, with tags before and after "It Works".

Try

```
If ($WebResponse.Content.Contains("It Works")) {
    Write-Host "OK"
} else {
    Restart-Service $service -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did some modification to my script and now it works. Thanks guys!

```
$WebResponse= Invoke-WebRequest     https://websit.com
$service = 'service'
$logoutput = 'service restarted'
$Date = Get-Date
if ($WebResponse -match "It Works") {
Write-Host "OK"
} else {
Restart-Service $service -Force
"$Date, $logoutput" | Out-File -FilePath   C:\log.txt -Append
}
```